# Creating a database table for storing filter criteria in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models

I have a problem. I've been banging my head against the wall for about 4 days now. I know I'm missing something, but I'm just not sure what it is.

I'm trying to store a certain set of filter criteria. Basically a user of my site will see a page where they can select different criteria for filtering users of another site (say twitter).

In the page, there will be a main criteria (which is dropdown) : 
1) Tweeted at (in which case a textfield will appear next to it for entering a twitter handle)
2) Had tweets more than (in which case a number field will appear next to it)
3) Tweeted between (in which case two date fields 'from' and 'to' will appear next to it)

So a basic flow would be like :
1) User chooses 'Tweeted at' as main criteria
2) A text input box appears next to it
3) User enters 'coldplay'
4) A list of twitter users who have tweeted at Coldplay is returned

Phew! Ok, now the problem. I'm not sure how to store filter criteria in a table (say named Filters).

### I tried the following :

1. Single Table = Col 1 - Filter_id, Col 2 - Filter name, Col 3 - Tweeted_at (charfield),
   Col 4 - No:of tweets (int field for 'had tweets more than' option), Col 5 - From_Date, Col 6 - To_Date, Col 7 - User_ID. The Problem with this is, its too, I don't know wasteful (?). There will always be some 'NULL' values depending on the main criteria chosen. It just seems like bad design because if I wanted to add a new criteria the schema would change. And I don't think if I had a good design the schema would change often. (Ideally only the rows should increase/decrease not the columns)
2. Split into multiple tables :- 1) FilterInstance - Col 1 -Filter_id, Col 2 - Value, Col 3 - UserId. 2)FilterDefinition - Col 1 - Filter_id, Col 2 - Filter_name, Col 3 - Type. The problem with this is that I don't know what data type I have to put for 'Value' in FilterInstance. If I put string then if the datatype is date, I'd have to go into extracting the mm/dd/yyyy manually. So again, I'm stuck. But this does however fix my schema changing problem.

---

So, I'd like to know how experienced people would design the structure for the table. I know I'm missing something. I just don't know what it is. I'm implementing this in django, so if you have an idea specific to django that'd be ok as well I guess. Though ideally, I would wanna know if there is some cool way of structuring the table.

---

Edit : I should also mention that I'd like to also map which user performed a particular filter.